# KnockoutJS 3.1.0: "with" binding and transitions

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

in one of my projects, I've been using KnockoutJS 2.2.1 for a long time. I've been using a custom directive to animate object changes through sliding, something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withSliding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.with.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        slideOut(function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.with.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            slideIn();
        });
    }
};
```

Now I want to update to Knockout 3.1.0. But the issue is: "with" binding is now missing the "update" subproperty of "ko.bindingHandlers.with". Therefore, there's no way to defer the template updates.

Any solutions?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, directly calling the `init` and `update` functions of a binding handler isn't supported by Knockout. In Knockout 3.1, the `with` binding does all updating in its `init` function, so there isn't a way to intercept it anyway.

Knockout does provide a binding with a standard way of intercepting added or removed content - the `foreach` binding. Starting with Knockout 3.0, there's also a way to wrap other bindings, using the [`preprocess` function](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-preprocessing.html). Putting these two together, here's what your `withSliding` binding could look like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withSliding = {
    preprocess: function (value, name, addBinding) {
        addBinding('foreach', 
            '{'+
                'data:[ko.unwrap('+ value +')],'+
                'beforeRemove:function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).slideUp(function() { $(elem).remove(); })},'+
                'afterAdd:function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().slideDown()}'+
            '}'
        );
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/wRbzL/ (using RP Niemeyer's template)

Alternatively, your custom binding can just do everything (without wrapping any other binding).

```
ko.bindingHandlers.withSliding = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var $element = $(element),
            template = $element.children().clone();
        $element.hide();

        ko.computed(function() {
            var dataValue = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            $element.slideUp(function () {
                $element.empty();
                if (dataValue) {
                    $element.append(template.clone()).hide();
                    ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext.createChildContext(dataValue), element);
                    $element.slideDown();
                }
            });
        }, null, { disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved: element });

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/pzsCX/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options that I can think of:

- if you don't care about the transition out (you seem to be sliding out, so you probably do care), then you could place a simple `slideIn` binding on the first element inside the container that has the `with` binding. In the binding's `init` function you could hide the element and then slide it in.
- Otherwise, the you could choose to wrap the `template` binding rather than the `with` binding. If you pass an options object to the `template` binding and exclude the `name` property, then it will use the child element's as its anonymous template.

In the `update` function, you would also want to make sure that you access any observable dependencies synchronously (not just in an async callback), so that it fires again.

Maybe something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.templateSliding = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        return ko.bindingHandlers.template.init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);
    },

    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var data, options = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());

        if (options && options.data) {
            //make sure that we have a dependency on the template's data
            data = ko.unwrap(options.data);   
        }

        $(element).slideUp("fast", function () {
            ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext);

            if (data) {
                $(element).slideDown();
            }
        });            
    }
};
```

Sample: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/G3dn4/

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! It _sort of_ works, but I clearly see that HTML template is being updated before the `ko.bindingHandlers.template.update(...)` call. Is there any explanation/walkaround for this?

Comment: there are a couple of scenarios where the update would happen in an internal computed set up for the template, this would include when the template name is observable. What does your scenario look like (what data are you passing for the template config)?  You should be able to do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/M59RB/. I'll see if I can find some time to look at other options.